# Checklist for merging changes in a Figma branch of a Design System library

Tags: design-system

Does anyone follow any checklists when reviewing and approving branch changes in a design system library and if so, what kind of things would you check to maintain quality in your design system.

Answer (score 0):

Figma has provided some useful documentation about the [best practices for branching](https://www.figma.com/best-practices/branching-in-figma/), which follows very closely to how version control is maintained in software development.

Probably the most basic checklist for merging changes in a figma branch is to adopt or extend the process you have for introducing design changes to a design system (there might be a separate team that manages this, and have their own process for this).

I imagine that when you open a branch, it is for the purpose of testing something out which is a variation from the main design system, so you don't want multiple branches open because the process for merging would be much more difficult. So the minimum checklist would be:

- ensure that there are no other dependent branches open (if so then you should close or merge those the precede it where possible)
- ensure that there is a review by another design before it is handed back to the person responsible for merging the branch
- ensure that the review process includes checking for impact at system and local levels
- ensure that the next steps after merging is triggered (e.g. communication to project teams working on that feature or component

In terms of the actual checks you have to do against the design system, that will depend on how your design system is set up, and there's probably too much details and variations to go into here.